# Grouping EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I was wondering if there is a way to group **EditText** in a way that you can only traverse among a group of them.

[image: Diagram]

The problem is that I rely on reaching the end of the first group and use `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE` in order to trigger a certain action.

The inner group of **EditText**s is inside a **LinearLayout**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the text boxes in a layout(linear or relative) only those EditText which you want to make a group. layout will act as group. Add this on your every Edittext xml--

```
 android:maxLines="1"
```

if it does not works the you can handle focus.

**Focus Handling** 
Focus movement is based on an algorithm which finds the nearest neighbor in a given direction. In rare cases, the default algorithm may not match the intended behavior of the developer.

Change default behaviour of directional navigation by using following XML attributes:

```
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/.."  
android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/.."    
android:nextFocusRight="@+id/.."    
android:nextFocusUp="@+id/.."
```

Besides directional navigation you can use tab navigation. For this you need to use

```
android:nextFocusForward="@+id/.."
```

To get a particular view to take focus, call

```
view.requestFocus()
```

To listen to certain changing focus events use a View.OnFocusChangeListener

**Keyboard button**

You can use android:imeOptions for handling that extra button on your keyboard.

Additional features you can enable in an IME associated with an editor to improve the integration with your application. The constants here correspond to those defined by imeOptions.
The constants of imeOptions includes a variety of actions and flags, see the link above for their values.

**Value example**

ActionNext :

the action key performs a "next" operation, taking the user to the next field that will accept text.
ActionDone :

the action key performs a "done" operation, typically meaning there is nothing more to input and the IME will be closed.

**Code example:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ems="10" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you want to listen to imeoptions events use a TextView.OnEditorActionListener.

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
            performSearch();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

**Edit:**
For dynamic edittext you can try..

```
EditText etCurrent;
```

Set an OnTouchlistener on each EditText:

```
valueET.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            if (etCurrent != null) {
                if (etCurrent.getId() != v.getId()) {

                    if (!check(etCurrent.getId())) {
                        etCurrent.setSelection(0,
                             etCurrent.getText().toString().length());
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        etCurrent = (EditText) v;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                etCurrent = (EditText) v;
            }
      }
    return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: The two groups of EditText are in different LinearLayouts, but once you reach the end of the first, it still goes onto the other group, adding  maxLines doesn't change that.
I liked the focus handle idea but the EditText are dynamic and can have multiple groups at a time so I would have to create Id's each time one is created and that seems like a bad idea.

Comment: but without creating Ids how you can get Editext contents after ime action done

Comment: Well all EditText are created in java, so I have reference to the java object itself I don't need xml Id's

Comment: Yea I ended up doing something along those lines actually. Just wanted to know if there was a simpler way to do it by somehow grouping the editTexts.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well I use the .setOnEditorActionListener on every EditText and detect if the actionId  == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT, and if that is true, I check if the EditText that triggered the action is equal to the final EditText in the arraylist of EditText's that I have stored.